# Multiple overriding 'keyup' events

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, I am listening to the keyups on a text input like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
```

This works fine, however I also want to listen for the user pressing the UP or DOWN key anywhere in the rest of the document - so I tried adding the following (hoping jquery would use the input one inside the text box and the global one for anything else):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
```

It has not done this, and chooses the global keyup for everything now. Is there any way I can get Jquery to do what I need here? I feel like it should be choosing the 'most specific' key up in each case, but it seems not...

Comment: How are you determining which one it is using? Because it should fire both, unless you're using `stopPropagation()` or `preventDefault()` somewhere.

Comment: Standard event propagation goes from most nested elements in DOM to root, so those events should work or You stoped event propagation in callback.

Comment: You guys seem to be right, testing on JSFiddle it calls both, must be something I'm doing wrong somewhere, I'm not stopping propogation though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this way for listening to the user when pressing the UP key anywhere from entire document elements with exception for input[type='text']

```
<script>
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
           if($(e.target).is('[type="text"]')){
              return; <!-- you can handle keyup of input type text in this block -->
           } 
           else {
                <!-- handle your keyup of ducument code here -->
           }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you. I still don't know why my local js isn't calling both functions, but this negates the need for that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :) and Always remember there is no need to make complex code

Answer (score 1):

It should be running both handlers, starting with the one for the more specific element. But if it's not, you can change the second handler so it doesn't overlap.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ":not(:text)", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

`:text` is a shorthand selector for `input[type=text]`, and `:not()` excludes them in this binding.

Comment: You are correct, I tried it on a JSFiddle and it ran both starting with the most specific, which makes sense. I'm not sure why it's not doing it on mine locally. Additionally, the ':not(:text)' didn't seem to work on the JSFiddle

Comment: Can you provide a link to your fiddle?